# Strange behavior on FBSession login

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa-touch, facebook-graph-api

I am having a hard time trying to login and logout using FBSession

When I run my app, try to call Login Action and Check after, it displays I'm not authenticated, if I close the app, enter again and call Check action again, it shows it is connected... very strange

there are not a lot of good material out there about this, any tips?

```
  -(IBAction)Check
    {
        if(FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded)
        {
            [lblLoading setText:@"Connected"];
            NSLog(@"Connected");
        }
        else
        {
            [lblLoading setText:@"Not Conn"];
            NSLog(@"No");
        }
    }

    -(IBAction)Logout
    {
        NSLog(@"Logut called");
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        [FBSession.activeSession close];
        FBSession.activeSession = nil;

        self.Check;
    }

    -(IBAction)Login
    {
        NSLog(@"Login called");

        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];

        self.Check;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the login status immediately after logging in, the app is not logged in. You can wait for the Delegate method `fbDidLogin` to know you have successfully logged in and there start `self.Check`. You can also try this by having a third button to just `self.Check` just after logging in.